# Can I install both NTP server & NTP client on same machine (linux)?

Tags: rhel, ntp, ntpd

Here's my use case :

I have 2 independent networks & 3 servers. Server 1 & 2 are connected on Network 1 (172.24.xx.xxx) while Servers 2 & 3 are connected via network 2 (locally : 192.168.1.x).

Now, Server 1 has a NTP server configured. So, I configured a NTP client on Server 2. Everything works fine till now.

But, now I also need to synchronize the Server 3 (on local network). So, can I install both NTP server & client on Server 2, such that NTP client daemon syncs with Server 1 & NTP server daemon connects with Server 3.

Comment: You don't need both client and server program installed on server 2. This is X-Y. Even when you really want Y, you want to know how to do that, while the whole question is can you do that. Also, this question shows no personal effort at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, please explain what you meant by that. I don't have any connectivity between Server 3 & Server 1. So, how am I supposed to sync with it without using Server 2 as a mediator.

Answer (score 2):

NTP dæmons are both clients and servers. They can receive time from “servers” (using the `server` directive in the configuration file), exchange time information with peers, and provide time to clients (if they consider their clocks to be accurate enough).

You should configure NTP on server 3, connected to server 2. Everything should “just work” then, at least as long as server 2 remains connected to server 1, but you’ll probably want to investigate the configuration file a bit more in order to control where time information is retrieved from and forwarded to.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `ntpd` (server) on server 1, just add an `ntpd` to server 2, telling it to synchronize from server 1 (via network 1). Then add another `ntpd` on server 3, telling it to synchronize from server 2 (via network 2). `ntpd` is both, server *and* client.